# google analytics и fragment

Tags: android, google-analytics

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь добавить google analytics в приложение, чтоб отслеживать на каком экране находятся пользователи, но сложность в том что у меня fragmentactivity а в ней фрагменты. Пробовал с v3 и v4, как указано по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883613/using-google-analytics-to-track-fragments, но безуспешно. С fragmentactivity все просто получается, на примере v3, создал файл analytics.xml, и :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
}
```

И на странице https://www.google.com/analytics, сразу видно имя активного экрана, кол-во пользователей и т.д. Но как этого добиться с фрагментами, чтоб было видно на каком фрагменте находится пользователь??? Прошу помочь.

Comment: Мне кажется это так было вообще в старой версии аналитики, которая была не через google play service ? зачем она вам ? Вот у меня сейчас в проект как написано, там вообще нигде activity не участвует - что хотите то и задаете: Tracker t = ((MyAnalytics)getApplication()).getTracker(MyAnalytics.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
  t.setScreenName(this.getClass().getName());
        t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());

Comment: т.е. сама вот эта конструкция EasyTracker.getInstance(this) насколько я понял устарела уже.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно я занимался глупостями. Переделал на v4 и в setOnPageChangeListener слушаю какой фрагмент на экране и отправляю то что мне надо. Спасибо)))

Comment: @Evgeny, оформите, пожалуйста, написанное вами в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструкция EasyTracker.getInstance(this) насколько я понял устарела уже.
Так было вообще в старой версии аналитики, которая была не через google play service ? зачем она вам ?
У меня сейчас в проект так написано, там вообще нигде activity не участвует - что хотите то и задаете:

```
Tracker t = ((MyAnalytics)getApplication()).getTracker(MyAnalytics.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
t.setScreenName(this.getClass().getName());
t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

на всякий случай приведу код класса MyAnalytics

```
public class MyAnalytics extends Application {

    // The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "SET_YOUR_ID";

    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public MyAnalytics() {
        super();
    }

    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(
                            R.xml.global_tracker)
                            : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
            t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```